# Capturing year of a DATE in SQL Worksheet (Datameer)

Tags: sql

In Datameer, how do you capture the year of a DATE column in a SQL worksheet?

This query

```
SELECT YEAR(rslt_part.draw_date) AS YEAR, COUNT(*) AS CT FROM
rslt_part
GROUP BY YEAR
```

is returning the following error:

> "Encountered 'AS YEAR'... was expecting one of:  "ORDER" ... "LIMIT" ... "OFFSET" ... "FETCH" ... "FROM" ... "," ... "AS"  ... "AS"  ... "AS"  ... "AS"  ... "AS"  ... "UNION" ... "INTERSECT" ... "EXCEPT" ... "MINUS" ... "NOT" ... "IN" ... "<" ... "<=" ... ">" ... ">=" ... "=" ... "<>" ... "!=" ... "BETWEEN" ... "LIKE" ... "SIMILAR" ... "+" ... "-" ... "*" ... "/" ... "%" ... "||" ... "AND" ... "OR" ... "IS" ... "MEMBER" ... "SUBMULTISET" ... "CONTAINS" ... "OVERLAPS" ... "EQUALS" ... "PRECEDES" ... "SUCCEEDS" ... "IMMEDIATELY" ... "MULTISET" ... "[" ... "FILTER" ... "OVER" ..."

Comment: Have you tried renaming your alias as this is a reserved word ? `select YEAR(rslt_part.draw_date) AS YR, COUNT(*) AS CT ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try aliasing the `YEAR()` call to something other than `YEAR`, and also try repeating the function call in the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT YEAR(draw_date) AS yr, COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM rslt_part
GROUP BY YEAR(draw_date)
```